# Custom Hierarchy View-- NSTreeController or Not?

Tags: nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller, custom-view

I have a hierarchy of stuff I want to display (at the same time) in both outline view and a custom view.  Sort of analagous to the Buck and Yacktman (Cocoa Design Patterns) example in CH. 29, but with Outline instead of Table.  I'll most likely have a detail view available also.

I've only used NSTreeController with a single outline view before.  Now I have found that "arrangedObjects" aren't what one would like them to be.  Also found that (for some reason) all the 'canInsert' and it's relatives have value NO (for some reason I can't find (or find with google)).  So so far, it appears that NSTreeController is little help in coordinating my two views.  (By the way, I've always had my add, delete functions work directly on the model in the past.)

it seems to me now it would be better and simpler to go back to using a data source approach, and use an architecture more like Buck and Yacktman's figure 29.4 (page 357) with a handmade mediating controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been hanging around for quite a while with no takers.

Just to close this out:

I've tried both NSTreeController and data source versions.  Currently, I'm sticking with data source, since it seems to give me more flexibility.

-- The program I'm working on has been very much experimental, trying a number of different things.  A secondary goal is to make an application I will find useful, and ternaryily :-) maybe make a cleaned up version for distribution.

Comment: I currently playing with using different ideas for an inspector view and was considering using NSTreeController as the datasource. My hope was by backing my view with a tree controller I can simply manipulate the tree (adding/removing/moving items) and my custom view accordingly (I have to implement all that functionality myself of course!). I'm experienced with Cocoa but I've not attempted anything like this before do you know where I could find some example project which use a controller class to back a custom view in this way? Either NSArrayController or NSTreeController projects?

Comment: I don't know of any off hand. I pretty much abandoned the experimental thing I was working on when I asked this question in favor of something I thought I knew how to do. It's been slow going with the amount of time I've had to work on it. Good luck.